# How to draw a half circle of rectangulars in flutter?

Tags: flutter, canvas, paint

I am trying to draw a half-circle made of custom shape not just a simple line.

Here is an example of what I desire. I refer at gray rectangulars.

[image]

Is here anybody who knows how to do that? I would be greateful!

Comment: Are you referring to doing something like using [CustomPainter](https://zocada.com/drawing-custom-shapes-in-flutter-using-custompainter/)?

Comment: Yes. I am new to canvas in Flutter and I need some help because i didn't find a satisfying tutorial or documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Below is my code:

```
Paint rectPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.grey
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.darken
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    for (double angle = 180; angle >= 0; angle = angle - 6) {
      double angleInRadians = angle * math.pi / 180;

      double x = radius * math.cos(angleInRadians);
      double y = radius * math.sin(angleInRadians);
      y -= radius;
      y = -y;
      x += size.width / 2;
      canvas.save();
      canvas.translate(x, y + 27);
      canvas.rotate(-angleInRadians);
      canvas.drawRect(
          Rect.fromCenter(height: 4, width: 16, center: Offset(0, 0)),
          rectPaint);
      canvas.restore();
    }
```

Hope will be helpful for someone.

Comment: I think you need this line as well before you use `radius`: `double radius = min(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);`

Comment: @JacobRussell Yes, you can set it as you said. In my case I send it as a parameter.