# Semi circular wheel in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

[image]How I can make this design in flutter. And my thinking is to gave a scrolling feature to the semi circle while scrolling it will change the value. the pointer is static. Any idea or suggestions help me. And if possible please provides a solutions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pskink/5fd59d240beb8dd9d780f978e5c76b3c#file-sized_content_scrollable-dart-L250

Comment: I did something similar. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63884085/how-to-draw-a-half-circle-of-rectangulars-in-flutter